# How to access embedded attachments?

Tags: c#, mimekit

I am using MailKit/MimeKit 1.2.7 (latest NuGet version).

I am using ImapClient to receive emails that can have diverse attachments (images, text files, binary files, etc).

MimeMessage's `Attachment` property helps me access all these attachments --- unless the emails are being sent with Apple Mail **and** contain images (it seems that Apple Mail does not attach images with Content-Disposition "attachment" (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170852/strip-attachments-from-emails-using-mailkit-mimekit) ... comment from Jeffrey Stedfast at the very bottom).

Embedded images are **not** listed in the Attachments collection.

What are my options? Do I really have to traverse the body parts one by one and see what's inside? Or is there an easier solution?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Working with Messages](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Working-With-Messages.htm) document lists a few ways of examining the MIME parts within a message, but another simple option might be to use the `BodyParts` property on the `MimeMessage`.

To start, let's take a look at how the `MimeMessage.Attachments` property works:

```
public IEnumerable<MimeEntity> Attachments {
    get { return BodyParts.Where (x => x.IsAttachment); }
}
```

As you've already noted, the reason that this property doesn't return the attachments you are looking for is because they do not have `Content-Disposition: attachment` which is what the `MimeEntity.IsAttachment` property is checking for.

An alternate rule might be to check for a filename parameter.

```
var attachments = message.BodyParts.Where (x => x.ContentDisposition != null && x.ContentDisposition.FileName != null).ToList ();
```

Or maybe you could say you just want all images:

```
var images = message.BodyParts.OfType<MimePart> ().Where (x => x.ContentType.IsMimeType ("image", "*")).ToList ();
```

Hope that gives you some ideas on how to get the items you want.

Comment: Yes, both code snippet worked perfectly for me. In fact I need both (first find all attachments and second give some special treatment to the images). Thank you, Jeffrey! This helped a lot!!

Comment: Warning: inline images might still have no content-disposition set. Don't use the 2nd snippet of the answer